# A basic question on gradient

Tags: optimization, partial-derivative

I am not understanding why gradient will show the direction in which the function value rises most quickly. It is just the vector of partial derivatives of the function. And why its magnitude will determine how fast the temperature rises in that direction.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is one of the crucial concepts in multivariable calculus. The key point is this: For a differentiable function $f$, the *directional derivative* at $P$ in direction $\vec v$ is given by $D_{\vec v}f(P)=\nabla f(P)\cdot\vec v$. By the basic formulas for dot product, this means that the directional derivative is *largest* when $\vec v$ points in the direction of $\nabla f(P)$. That is, $\vec v$ gives the direction in which $f$ increases at the greatest rate at $P$. And, for a unit vector $\vec v$ in this direction, we have $D_{\vec v}f(P) = \nabla f(P)\cdot\vec v = \|\nabla f(P)\|$, which tells you that the magnitude of the gradient gives the greatest possible rate of increase of $f$ at $P$.